# Rename grok to grok-framework to avoid confusion with logstash-grok

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [grok tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grok) (Grok is a web framework) is mostly used for questions referring to the grok filter of logstash, which has its own tag ([logstash-grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logstash-grok)). Currently 313 of the 455  question of the grok tag are [about logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logstash+grok) and are most likely mis-tagged.

It would it be possible to rename the grok tag to something like grok-framework to reduce errors?

What do you think?

Comment: It'd be better to retag the ones which are mistagged *instead* of doing fancy work with the tag instead.  Let me stress that **you should not do this on your own**, but wait until there's a reasonable consensus about what to do with this tag.

Comment: @Makoto the issue with just retagging is that, I think, we'll end in the same place in one or two years: If users don't read the tag description today (and yesterday), I don't see how they'll start now. Since I'm regularly following the Logstahs tag, I'm correcting it when I see that tag error (but only on new questions).

Comment: People don't look at the tag descriptions *today* and haven't for years, since this is a persistent and ongoing thing we have to deal with as one of our inner working operations.  So let's address this issue today and deal with whatever future issue will result from people continuing to mistag their posts when that reaches another tipping point.